# Adding a fixed square in Mapbox gl?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mapbox-gl-js

I know it is possible to add lines, points or polygons by adding a geojson source in Mapbox gl, these would be located on the map through coordinates. However, what I am trying to do is adding a simple polygon that would be fixed on the canvas, and would remain at the same position of the canvas - not the globe - even if the user pans or zooms.

(Note that I am aware that this could be achieved by resetting the data of the initial geojson on zoom/pan, but the figure would then glitch).

I would appreciate any idea, thanks.

Comment: If you just want a box that doesn't move why draw in WebGL? Just make a div and position with with CSS?

Comment: Wouldn't that make the area non scrollable? I don't want to loose the map controls - zoom/pan - over the area where the square is, if that make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by non scrollable? Would `pointer-events: none;` handle it?

Comment: Actually you're absolutely right!! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a box that doesn't move why draw in WebGL? Just make a div and position with with CSS?

The [example on this page](https://www.mapbox.com/help/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-1/) has 2 div based rectangles. One says "*US population density*" and the other is the legend.

If the mouse is over them they block scrolling.

If I right click on one and pick "inspect" I see it has a "map-overlay" CSS class. If I add `pointer-events: none` to it suddenly I can scroll

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the job :)